# Exception class that inherits from system.dividebyzeroexception

Tags: vb.net

I have created a inherited class named ZeroException that inherits from System.DivideByZero Class but when a dividebyzero exception occurs it doesnt catch the event.

```
Class ZeroException
Inherits System.DivideByZero
Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Message() as String
Get 
Return "Divide By Zero"
End Get
End Property
End Class
```

Main Code:

```
Sub Calc()
dim x as integer=5
dim y as integer=0
dim k as single

Try   
k=x\y 'Integer Division
Catch ex as ZeroException  
Console.WriteLine(ex.Message) 'But I get another message. Not Divide By Zero
End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: You've got that backwards.  You can't catch a more derived exception.

Answer (score 4):

you dont catch a custom exception but rather you throw one.. so in this case your code should look like follows:

```
    Try
        k = x \ y 'Integer Division
    Catch ex As DivideByZeroException
        Throw New ZeroException
    End Try
```

Here is a test case that demonstrates this.

```
Imports System.Text
Imports Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting

Class ZeroException
    Inherits DivideByZeroException
    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Message() As String
        Get
            Return "Divide By Zero"
        End Get
    End Property
End Class

<TestClass()> Public Class UnitTest1

    <TestMethod()> Public Sub TestMethod1()
        Try
            MethodThrowsCustomException()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Sub MethodThrowsCustomException()
        Dim x As Integer = 5
        Dim y As Integer = 0
        Dim k As Single

        Try
            k = x \ y 'Integer Division
        Catch ex As DivideByZeroException
            Throw New ZeroException
        End Try

    End Sub

End Class
```